# Fast way to query latest record?

Tags: sql, performance, oracle

I have a table of the sort:

```
USER |  PLAN |  START_DATE  |   END_DATE
1    |  A    |  20110101    |   NULL
1    |  B    |  20100101    |   20101231
2    |  A    |  20100101    |   20100505
```

In a way that if `END_DATE` is `null`, means that this user has that plan currently active.

What I want to query is:
(a) the current plan he has active, or (b) the lastest plan he was into. I need only one row returned for each given user.

Now, I managed to do that in using unions and sub queries, but it happens that table is massive and these are not efficient enough.
Would any of you guys have a quicker way to query that?

Thanks,

[EDIT]
Most answers here return a single value. That was my bad. What I meant was to return a single value per user but all users at once. I've adapted the answers I could (and corrected the question) but just making it clear for future reference.

Comment: Do you have indexes on the columns you are querying on?

Comment: Sort of. I have the indexes I need and the do improve the query, it's just the logic I'm using that bugs me... Really think that should be some better way of doing it.

Comment: Do you have a compound index on user and end_date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is  a little hard to answer without further information about the data and the table. When you say in your comment that you have all the indexes that you need, what are these indexes?

Also, are the time periods abutting and non-overlapping? Can you just get the period with the latest START_DATE?

The problem with looking at END_DATE is that a normal B-Tree index doesn't index NULLs. So, a predicate of the form `where end_date is nulll` is unlikely to use the index. You could use a bitmap index with the column as those type of indexes do index nulls but that might not be ideal because of some of the other drawbacks of bitmap indexes.

For the reasons given above, I would probably use a query similar to the one below:

```
select user, plan, start_date, end_date
from (
  select 
    user, 
    plan, 
    start_date, 
    end_date, 
    row_number() over (partition by user order start_date desc) as row_num_1,
    row_number() over (partition by user order end_date desc nulls first) as row_num_2
  from user_table
  where user = :userid
)
where row_num_1 = 1
```

You could probably use either the `row_num_1` or the `row_num_2` column here depending on the exact requirements.

OR

```
select user, plan, start_date, end_date
from (
  select 
    user, 
    plan, 
    start_date, 
    end_date, 
  from user_table
  where user = :userid
  order by start_date desc
)
where rownum = 1
```

The first query should work whether you are trying get all the users back or just one. The second query will only work with one user.

If you can augment the question with more details of the schema (indexes, meaning of the start/end date) you are likely to get better answers.

Comment: After a little bit of reading, it seems my comment above about indexes and NULLs isn't strictly true. It is the case that NULLs aren't indexed if all the column values for a given index are NULL. So, for example an index on END_DATE alone wouldn't index the NULLs, but an index on {USER, PLAN, END_DATE} would index NULLs (probably. I think.)

Comment: Phew. Good point. The whole information will make the question a lot more complex. Sorry for oversimplifying. I just thought my problem was the ugly construction with sub queries and unions rather than the underlying structure. Just to give some detail, there is no actual "user" table, this is already a sub query table joining of two large entities. I have the indexes (bthrees) for all the columns I'm using in the join and for the dates (end and star days). Thanks for the nice comment! Oh, mind my last edit, I'm looking for retrieving all users and plans at once

Comment: @filippo I've just added some further details to my answer. The first query should work with all users if you need it. I've also added an option such that you can use `end_date` instead of `start_date`. I guess it's pretty hard to simplify some problems enough to be able to ask a reasonable question. I had guessed that you'd changed something since `USER` isn't even a valid column name as it's a reserved word.

Comment: Hi. I'm picking yours as correct. Actually the option from srinu was pretty darn fast, but I couldn't get the time to implement it properly for my needs. Also, there were more people here posting the same answer as yours, but you've got better explanation. Thanks!

Comment: @filippo - Just had a look at the answer from srinu. Both of our answers should give mostly the same result and should be similar in terms of performance. Difference between `DENSE_RANK` ad `ROW_NUMBER` is that row number will be strictly unique. For example, if you have two rows for a given user with the same end date (I'm guessing you shouldn't) then `ROW_NUMBER` will number those 1 and 2 (and could be non-deterministic), but `DENSE_RANK` will number them both 1 and return both of them. I think the `NULLS FIRST` is necessary to make this work too as it gets out the current plan.

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE XY
( USERID      INTEGER                 NOT NULL
, PLAN        VARCHAR2(8)             NOT NULL
, START_DATE  DATE                    NOT NULL
, END_DATE    DATE                    )
  TABLESPACE USERS;


INSERT INTO XY ( USERID, PLAN, START_DATE, END_DATE )
       VALUES ( 1, 'A', To_Date('22-05-2011 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), To_Date('22-05-2011 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') );
INSERT INTO XY ( USERID, PLAN, START_DATE, END_DATE )
       VALUES ( 1, 'B', To_Date('01-04-2011 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), NULL );
INSERT INTO XY ( USERID, PLAN, START_DATE, END_DATE )
       VALUES ( 2, 'A', To_Date('03-05-2011 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), To_Date('04-05-2011 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') );
INSERT INTO XY ( USERID, PLAN, START_DATE, END_DATE )
       VALUES ( 2, 'B', To_Date('15-05-2011 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), To_Date('20-05-2011 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') );
COMMIT WORK;

SELECT USERID, PLAN, END_DATE, START_DATE
  FROM (SELECT USERID,
               PLAN,
               END_DATE,
               START_DATE,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY USERID ORDER BY END_DATE DESC) SEQUEN
          FROM XY)
 WHERE SEQUEN < 2
```

Comment: Thanks. This is pretty much the same as MikeyByCrikey said. He's just got a longer explanation.

Answer (score 1):

This may help:

```
SELECT user,plan,end_date,start_date 
FROM ( SELECT users,plans,end_date,start_date, DENSE_RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY user 
                                                                   ORDER BY end_date DESC) sequen 
        FROM table_name 
     ) 
WHERE sequen <= 2
```

Comment: Yey.. This is sure pretty fast, but got me studding the dense_rak thing. Would you mind giving some more details on what you did here? (sorry for the newbness!) thanks

Comment: Probably adding `NULLS FIRST` in the `ORDER BY` clause makes it clearer.

Comment: Shouldnt `sequen` be strictly < 2 ?

Comment: @APC, too bad lad. I do my googling, mind you. Can't see why would asking for details in a short answer get such rude feedback. flagged.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to limit the resultset with `rownum`?

```
select  plan
from    (
        select  plan
        from    YourTable
        where   User = 1
        order by
                case when end_date is null then '99991231' else end_date end desc
        )
where   rownum < 2
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Using `CASE` and sub queries will cause your query to become very slow. So better to use them with care. How About:

```
SELECT User, Plan, start_Date, MAX(End_Date) FROM Plans WHERE User NOT IN 
(SELECT User FROM Plans WHERE End_Date IS NULL)
GROUP BY Start_Date, Plan, User  
UNION  
SELECT User,Plan,Start_Date FROM Plans WHERE End_Date IS NULL
```

I'm not a SQL guru. consider this just as a suggestion.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Funny :) this is exactly the select I currently using... this is the unfortunately this seems too slow. I really with I could do this with less sub-queries :/

Comment: owa. I should have read my own comment before posting it, terrible spelling, sorry. I'm trying most options people posted here I'll set as answer the one that suits best.

Comment: @filippo: Thanks. could be very helpful later.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
SELECT U.user 
,(SELECT Plan FROM t WHERE t.user=u.user AND end_date IS NULL LIMIT 1) AS Current_Plan
,(SELECT Plan FROM t WHERE t.user=u.user AND end_date IS NOT NULL ORDER BY end_date DESC LIMIT 1) AS Last_Plan
FROM 
( SELECT DISTINCT USER FROM t ) AS U
```

If it is slow, please send us the EXPLAIN output for the query.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
select PLAN
from USER_TABLE
where END_DATE is null or END_DATE = (
        select max(END_DATE)
        from USER_TABLE
        where USER = 1 and END_DATE is not null)
    and USER = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following :

```
with t as 
(select 1 as col_id, 1 as USER_id, 'A' as PLAN , 20110101 as START_DATE, NULL as  END_DATE from dual union all
 select 2,1,'B', 20100101,20101231 from dual union all
 select 3,2,'A', 20100102,20100505 from dual union all
 select 4,2,'C', 20100101,20100102 from dual)
--
SELECT user_id, plan
  FROM (SELECT user_id,
               plan,
               MAX(nvl(END_DATE, 99999999)) over(PARTITION BY user_id) max_date,
               nvl(END_DATE, 99999999) END_DATE
          FROM t)
 WHERE max_date = end_date
```