# ETL for processing history records

Tags: performance, oracle, etl

I am in sort of a DWH project (not quite, but still). And there is this issue we constantly run into which I was wondering if there would be a better solution. Follows

We receive some big files with records containing the all states a user have been into, like:

```
UID | State    | Date
1   | Active   | 20120518
2   | Inactive | 20120517
1   | Inactive | 20120517
...
```

And we are usually inly interested in the latest state of each user. So far so good, with just a little sorting and we could get the way we want it. Only problem is, these files are usually big.. like 20-60gb, sorting these guys sometimes is a pain since the logic for sorting isn't usually so straight forward.

What we do generally is load everything into our Oracle and use intermediary tables and materialized views to have it done. Still, sometimes performance bites us.

20-60gb might be big, but not *that* big. I mean, should be a somewhat more specialised way to deal with these records, shouldn't it?

I imagine two basic ways of seeing tackling the issue:

1) Programming outside the DBMS, scripts and compiled things. But maybe this is not very flexible unless some bigger amount of time is invested developing something. Also, I might have to busy myself administrating the box resources, whereas I wish not to worry with that.

2) Load everything into the DBMS (Oracle in my case) and use whatever tools it provide to sort and clip the data. This would be my case, though, I am not sure we are using all the tools or simply doing it the right way that would be for Oracle 10g.

Question is then:

You have a 60gb file with millions of historical records like the one above and your user want a table in DB with the last state for each user.

how would you guys do?

thanks!

Comment: how current do you need the data?  Meaning, do you need a snapshot of the latest states refreshed each week?  Every day? Every hour? Instantly?  This will of course affect your approach greatly.  Also, what is your db environment setup? (I assume some data factory env that pushes to a prod env every so often?)

Comment: I am not sure understand the last part of your question. As for the first part, is usually a weekly load. There isn't much of time constrain there, except of, I want it make it better :) The second part, you mean how we get the data, these are simply huge dump files from source systems with monitor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things you can do to speed up the process.

The first thing is to throw compute power at it.  If you have Enterprise Edition and lots of cores you will get  significant reductions in load time with parallel query.

The other thing is to avoid loading the records you don't want.  This is why you mention pre-processing the file.  I'm not sure there's much you can do there, unless you have access to a Hadoop cluster to run some map-reduce jobs on your file (well, reduce mainly, the structure you post is about as mapped as can be already).

But there is an alternative: external tables.  External tables are tables which have their data in OS files rather then tablespaces.  And they can be parallel enabled (providing your file meet certain criteria).  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm#i1007483).

So, you might have an external table like this

```
CREATE TABLE user_status_external (
   uid     NUMBER(6),
   status      VARCHAR2(10),
   sdate        DATE
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
(TYPE oracle_loader
 DEFAULT DIRECTORY data_dir
 ACCESS PARAMETERS
 (
  RECORDS DELIMITED BY newline
  BADFILE 'usrsts.bad'
  DISCARDFILE 'usrsts.dis'
  LOGFILE 'usrsts.log'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","  OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  (
   uid     INTEGER EXTERNAL(6),
   status     CHAR(10),
   sdate       date 'yyyymmdd' )
 )
 LOCATION ('usrsts.dmp')
)
PARALLEL
REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

Note that you need read and write permissions on the DATA_DIR directory object.

Having created the external table you can load the only desired data into your target table with an insert statement:

```
insert into user_status (uid, status, last_status_date)
    select  sq.uid
            ,  sq.status
            ,  sq.sdate
    from (
        select /*+ parallel (et,4) */ 
               et.uid
               , et.status
               , et.sdate
               , row_number() over (partition by et.uid order by et.sdate desc) rn  
        from user_status_external et
        ) sq
    where sq.rn = 1
```

---

Note that as with all performance advice, there are no guarantees. You need to benchmark things in your environment.

Another thing is the use of INSERT: I'm assuming these are all fresh USERIDs, as that is the scenario your post suggests.    If you have a more complicated scenario then you probably want to look at MERGE or a different approach altogether.

---

One last thing: you seem to be assuming this is a common situation, which has some standard approaches.  But most data warehouses load all the data they get.  They may then filter it for various different uses, data marts, etc.  But they almost always maintain a history in the actual warehouse of all the distinct records.  So that's why you might not get an industry standard solution.

Comment: This was very instructive. I knew of external tables and we even use it here and there as a quick way to load lookups. Didn't know they would be also good in cases like this. Nonetheless, the ETL product we're using does a pretty decent job in the loading part, I will try to combine both (my ETL + external table) and see how it goes. Oh, and for the sake of curiosity, yes, these are all fresh users. Thanks!

Comment: [There a proposal for a dedicated Q&A site for Business Intelligence. Follow, Post and Support to get it up.](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/70503/business-intelligence?referrer=EPHSm8-3avvaMxLjdRIeNg2)

Comment: @APC excellent mate and just freely post all the relevant BI questions you have or face or you think which penetrates the concepts. Because we need 40 quality questions in order to convince the SE that there's demand and why we need it. Infact BI is a separate business functionality although it access qulity data over databases.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with something along the lines of what APC said as a first go. However, I *think* parallel tables can only load data in parallel if the data is in multiple files, so you might have to cut the files into several.  How are the files generated?  A 20 - 60GB file is a real pain to deal with - can you get the generation of the files changed so you get X 2GB files for example?

After getting all the records into the database, you might run into problems attempting to sort 60GB of data - it would be worth having a look at the sort stage of the query you are using to extract the latest status.  In the past I helped large sorts by hash partitioning the data on one of the fields to be sorted, in this case user_id. Then Oracle only has to do X smaller sorts, each of which can proceed in parallel.

So, my thoughts would be:

1. Try and get many smaller files generated instead of 1 big one
2. Using External tables, see if it is feasible to extract the data you want directly from the external tables
3. If not, load the entire contents of the files into a hash partition table - at this stage make sure you do insert /*+ append nologging */ to avoid undo generation and redo generation. If your database has force_logging set to true, the nologging hint will have no effect.
4. Run the select on the staged data to extract only the rows you care about and then trash the staged data.

The nologging option is probably critical to you getting good performance - to load 60GB of data, you are going to generate at least 60GB of redo logs, so if that can be avoided, all the better. You would probably need to have a chat with your DBA about that!

Assuming you have lots of CPU available, it may also make sense to compress the data as you bulk load it into the staging table. Compression may well half the size of your data on disk if it has repeating fields - the disk IO saved when writing it usually more than beats any extra CPU consumed when loading it.

Comment: Interesting. Are you saying this with the parallel also apply for the staging tables? i.e. parallel queries will only run over partitioned data?

Comment: No - parallel will work on non-partitioned data too. However, consider a sort on customer_id - if you have partitioned the data on customer_id, then each partition can be totally sorted in isolation and then the sort partitions stacked together to create the entire sorted set. If all the data is in a non-partitioned table, the parallel query will sort chunks in parallel, but they will have to be merged afterwards. In the past I ran into data so large that it became very difficult to join or sort, and hash partitioning really sped it up (partition wise joins and faster sort if I recall).

Comment: My best advice is to get hold of production sized data on a test environment and experiment. Try compression, partitioning, splitting the input file into many. Should be an interesting project.

Comment: It is being fun indeed :) I've already got a big file in one test server and will be trying some different approaches. Mixing APC's suggestion with the ETL product we are using seems promising. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

I may be oversimplifying the problem, but why not something like:

```
create materialized view my_view
tablespace my_tablespace
nologging
build immediate
refresh complete on demand
with primary key
as
select uid,state,date from
(
  select /*+ parallel (t,4) */ uid, state, date, row_number() over (partition by uid order by date desc) rnum
  from my_table t;
)
where rnum = 1;
```

Then refresh fully when you need to.

Edit: Any don't forget to rebuild stats and probably throw a unique index on uid.

Comment: yep, that's pretty much what I do currently (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095928/fast-way-to-query-latest-record), sometimes with views, sometimes with intermediary tables, but that's the idea. I was just wondering if there would be some fancier techniques :)

Comment: why do u need fancier? ;-)  imo this is the best approach, u don't want to do a slow by slow method if your logic is simply find latest by date.  Also, its very evident by looking at the single underlying SQL what its doing (instead of a handful of scripts or procedures/functions).

Comment: Well, by fancier I meant _faster_. Something like pre-processing somehow the files a little bit outside the DBMS, or using some highly specialised function like these fast data-pumps. I thought finding the latest record was a common enough DWH problem to have some of the likes which I could be missing. Even this being a good solution, still takes long hours to process these files...

Comment: @filippo shouldn't take hours to refresh this view, even on large tables.  By "long hours to process these files" I don't know if you mean just the mat view refresh or some other steps (loading, etc), but your question was about the sort/find latest step (ie, the refresh for this approach).  Where is your performance pain point exactly? (what step/steps?)

Answer (score -1):

I would write a program to iterate over each record and retain only those which are more recent than record previously seen. At the end, insert the data into the database.

How practical that is would depend on how many users we're talking about - you could end up having to think carefully about your intermediate storage.

In general, this becomes (in pseudo-code):

```
foreach row in file
    if savedrow is null
        save row
    else
        if row is more desirable than savedrow
             save row
        end
    end
end

send saved rows to database
```

The point it, you need to define how one row is considered to be more desirable than another. In the simple case, for a given user, the current row's date is later than the last row we saved. At the end, you'd have a list of rows, one-per-user, each of which has the most recent date you saw.

You could general the script or program so that the framework is separate from the code that understands each data file.

It'll still take a while, mind :-)

Comment: Well, this is pretty much the concept of whatever tool I end up using man. It will have to be a lot more specific than that... The pseudo-code by the way, is probably not recommended, takes too much memory and processor. Here, this is the fastest one I have yet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095928/fast-way-to-query-latest-record